# using my own static/dinamic library: HOW TO compile and link against (the right way to do the things properly)

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, lib

Sorry for this newbie question.

**Context**:

I have just created my own library (using CMake):

```
libmyownsomething.a <--- static version of the compiled library
libmyownsomething.so <--- dinamic version of the same library
libmyownsomething.h <--- the header file to be included in other project
```

**Questions**:

- Where is the right place where the files should be placed? ( I **guest** `/usr/local/include/` and `/usr/local/lib/`
- How to compile other lib/projects against this one by inserting only `#include <myownsomething.h>` and a right flag `LDFLAGS=-lmyownsomething`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to link agains your library with just `-lmyownsomething`, you need to have `libmyownsomething.so` (or `.a`, for static linking) in one of the directories you linker searches by default.

I found this in texinfo documentation for GNU ld ([library search path in linker script](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html#IDX215)):

> 'SEARCH_DIR(PATH)'
>
> ```
>  The 'SEARCH_DIR' command adds PATH to the list of paths where 'ld'
>  looks for archive libraries.  Using 'SEARCH_DIR(PATH)' is exactly 
>  like using '-L PATH' on the command line
> ```

Now, GNU ld (`ld.bfd` to be precise) uses a default *linker script*, which can be obtained with `--verbose`. Let's see what search dirs there are by default (on my system, anyways -- that might well depend on configuration; if you are going to distribute your library, you probably want to make the most portable choice):

```
$ ld --verbose |& grep SEARCH_DIR 
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib");
```

To answer the question about `#include`ing files, you need to consult the compiler documentation, or perhaps the POSIX standard. (However, I'd recommend either going with the simplest choices -- see below -- or providing a configurable way to install your files e.g. with `--prefix` build time option. Then the user/packager can decide the best place to put them for themselves. But nothing keeps you from providing sane defaults. Same goes for libraries, but I tried to address that part of the question exactly how it was asked.)

Generally, this stuff varies from system to system, but they usually follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).  I think, `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` is the safest choice. Another good practice is using e.g. `pkgconf` mechanism.

Hope this helps. I really should have asked about your use-case first: who are you going to distribute your software to, and how? Anyway, be sure to post comments. Also, I wonder if this is Stackoverflow material; perhaps it needs moving some place else.